# trying to get an {% include header.html %} prompt to work

Tags: html, prepros

Trying to learn html and was trying to execute an include header.html, pulling information from an _includes folder that held the header.html file, but its not showing up on the local server. Using prepros as my server.

This is the result I'm getting --- --- {% include header.html %}

```
---
---

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>

    {% include header.html %}


<p> yar mi timbers </p>

<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Danger**: jQuery 2.1.1 is *beyond* End of Life and does not get security updates. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't HTML. It is some sort of template designed to output HTML when run through an appropriate compiler. Possibly [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#include).

You need to hook up a suitable compiler to your build system or server-side code.